# How to search an array using JSONPath in Java?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'd like to write a unit test for a web service using json-path-assert. Given this JSON:

```
[ 
  ["Some short name","Some parent","Some name"],
  ["Some short name 2","Some parent 2","Some name 2"] 
]
```

I'd like to check that the parent of "Some name 2" is "Some parent 2". I cannot change the structure of JSON since it is dictated by a third-party library.

Here's the JSONPath expression I came up with:

```
$..[?(@[2] == 'Some name 2')][1]
```

This expression works fine and gives returns the expected result ('Some parent 2') in [this JSON tool](http://www.jsonquerytool.com/). However when using it in Java using the JSONPath library I get an empty result instead of the correct value:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestJSONPath
{
  @Test
  public void testJsonPath() {
     String json = "[[\"Some short name\",\"Some parent\",\"Some name\"]," +
       "[\"Some short name 2\",\"Some parent 2\",\"Some name 2\"]]";

     System.out.println(JsonPath.read(json, "$[1][1]"));    // OK, returns 'Some parent 2'
     System.out.println(JsonPath.read(json, "$..[?(@[2] == 'Some name 2')][1]")); // Not OK, returns an empty list
 }
}
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Could you please help me with ideas how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could work:
`$[?(@[2] == 'Some name 2')][1]`

**Background:**

If you try the ["original" JSONPath implementation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/source/default/source) written by [Stefan Goessner](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), the following expression returns the expected array:

`$..[?(@[2] == 'Some name 2')]` (a descendant where value at index 2 is 'Some name 2')

`===> ["Some parent 2"]`

It is interesting... try these expressions with jayway, Goessners-JSON-lib or jsonquerytool :

```
"$..*" //list of all descendants (both child-arrays + elements in arrays)
"$.*" //list of all direct children (both child arrays)
"$" //actual element (the array itself)
```

Stefan Goessner's JavaScript library returns the same as the "jayway" implementation. But "jsonquerytool" gives `false` for `$` - which is definitively wrong. `$` is "the root object/element".

And for `$..*` this is the same result with all three implementations:

```
[
    [
        "Some short name",
        "Some parent",
        "Some name"
    ],
    [
        "Some short name 2",
        "Some parent 2",
        "Some name 2"
    ],
    "Some short name",
    "Some parent",
    "Some name",
    "Some short name 2",
    "Some parent 2",
    "Some name 2"
]
```

So `$..[?(@[2] == 'Some name 2')]` should match the array at index '1'... in my opinion, jayway is doing it wrong.

> With JSONPath square brackets operate on the object or array addressed by the previous path fragment. (see http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

Goessner is the inventor of JSONPath - so his implementation is doing it the right way!!! 
*summary:* jsonquerytool's and jayway's implementations are wrong.

Surprisingly this query is working as expected in all implementations (although `$` is `false` in jsonquerytool)

```
$[?(@[2] == 'Some name 2')][1]
```

also this version works:

```
$.[?(@[2] == 'Some name 2')][1]
```